# Same Period Last Month

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm struggling to get the same period of last month.
I want to compare the current month period, for instance, today is 16June2021 so I want to get the sales from May 1st to May 16th.

I'm using this formula but I get the whole month total:

Prev MTD = calculate(sum(Sales[Sales_Amount]),DATEADD(filter(DATESMTD(Sales[Sale_Date]),Sales[Sale_Date]<=today()),-1,MONTH))

Creating a table with DATEADD(filter(DATESMTD(Sales[Sale_Date]),Sales[Sale_Date]<=today()),-1,MONTH), I also get every day of last month.

Is it mandatory to use a Date Table? Already tried but the results came empty.
Is it something regarding my date format? From the import it comes as date/time format.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
Prev MTD = calculate(sum(Sales[Sales_Amount]),filter(ALL(Sales[Sale_Date]),Sales[Sale_Date] >= DATE( YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY())-1, 1) && Sales[Sale_Date]<=today()))
```

Answer (score 0):

where order_date between '2022-08-01' and DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(),32)
last month 31 days that's why i am calculated 32 days.
if last month 30 day than you need to calculate 31 days.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).